# Row-wise operation to see if any columns are in any other list

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a tibble `tib` as follows:

```
  A     B     C     D    
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 X123  X456  K234  V333 
2 X456  Z000  L888  B323 
3 X789  ZZZZ  D345  O999 
4 M111  M111  M111  M111 
.
.
.
(5000 rows)
```

I also have another vector as follows:

```
> vec <- c("X123","X456")
> vec
[1] "X123" "X456"
```

I am looking for a way to search for, and add a logical column (with 5000 rows, in the e.g.) to the right of the tibble that is either `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on whether any of the values of the columns in `tib` contain a value in `vec`. My goal output is the following:

```
  A     B     C     D      lgl
<chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <lgl>
1 X123  X456  K234  V333   TRUE
2 X456  Z000  L888  B323   TRUE
3 X789  ZZZZ  D345  O999   FALSE
4 M111  M111  M111  M111   FALSE
```

I have the following:

```
> tib %>% 
+   pmap_lgl(~any(..1 %in% vec))
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

This gets the results that I am seeking, but I'm a bit confused about the [syntax](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html).

Why does the above work (i.e. using `..1`), instead of having to use `..1`, `..2`, `..3`, and `..4`? My understanding is that `pmap` generates a vector based on the inputs rowwise, so I assume that `..1` in the above means the vector `c("X123","X456","K234","V333")` for row #1, `c("X456","Z000","L888","B323")` for row #2, etc.

In the end, I have two questions:

1. How do I append this new logical vector to the above `tib`? I haven't had any luck with:

`tib %>% mutate(lgl = pmap_lgl(~any(..1 %in% vec)))`

`Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots): Evaluation error: argument ".f" is missing, with no default.`

2. If I were to watch to access each column within each row (e.g. "X123" for the first row in pmap), how would I do that within the syntax of `purrr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `add_column` and `pmap_lgl` along with a helper function to get a `tidyverse` one-liner similar to the base `apply` solution from @YOLO.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(A = c('X123', 'X456','X789', 'M111'),
             B = c('X456', 'Z000', 'ZZZZ', 'M111'),
             C = c('K234', 'L888', 'D345', 'M111'),
             D = c('V333', 'B323', '0999', 'M111'))


vec <- c('V333', '0999')

check <- function(...) {

  any(c(...) %in% vec)

}

add_column(df, row_check = pmap_lgl(df, check))

# A tibble: 4 x 5
  A     B     C     D     row_check
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <lgl>    
1 X123  X456  K234  V333  TRUE     
2 X456  Z000  L888  B323  FALSE    
3 X789  ZZZZ  D345  0999  TRUE     
4 M111  M111  M111  M111  FALSE
```

The caveat of using `...` in the function is that it will operate over ALL columns of the provided tibble or data frame.  If you have additional columns you'll need to either specify the function arguments or limit the data passed to the `pmap_lgl`

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple, you could use base functions `apply` with `any` function:

```
df$lgl <- apply(df, 1, function(x) any(x %in% vec))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `..1`, `..2` refers to the number of arguments. We can use these along with the `mutate` and `rowwise` functions to get our desired result:

```
tib %>%
    mutate(lgl = pmap(., ~c(..1, ..2, ..3, ..4) %in% vec)) %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(lgl = any(unlist(lgl)))

  V1    V2    V3    V4    lgl  
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <lgl>
1 X123  X456  K234  V333  TRUE 
2 X456  Z000  L888  B323  TRUE 
3 X789  ZZZZ  D345  O999  FALSE
4 M111  M111  M111  M111  FALSE
```

The call to `pmap` uses `.` as its first argument, which is the function we're using. Then we create a vector of the values for each column using `c(..1, ..2, ..3, ..4)`. We need to then use `rowwise` to calculate the final logical value for each row.

The previous iteration of my answer would have returned an incorrect result for `vec = c('M111')`, it correctly performs it now:

```
tib %>%
    mutate(lgl = pmap(., ~c(..1, ..2, ..3, ..4) %in% c('M111'))) %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(lgl = any(unlist(lgl)))

  V1    V2    V3    V4    lgl  
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <lgl>
1 X123  X456  K234  V333  FALSE
2 X456  Z000  L888  B323  FALSE
3 X789  ZZZZ  D345  O999  FALSE
4 M111  M111  M111  M111  TRUE
```

[Here's a link](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html) to the documentation for the function, which might be useful too.

Comment: This isn't operating rowwise like OP requested.  If you change `vec` you'll see that you are still operating over the columns to the tibble.

Comment: Made a major revision to my answer. Thanks for noticing that.

Comment: No worries.  This still can be done without `rowwise` and nesting in a very concise manner.